# Android: View.isAttachedToWindow() is not in sync with actual state

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager

```
View new_overlay = new View(this);
wm.addView(new_overlay, params);
new_overlay.isAttachedToWindow(); //false here
```

I expected `isAttachedToWindow()` to be true after `addView()`. I haven't found documentation indicating that `addView()` is asynchronous.

Adding a sleep of several seconds before checking `isAttachedToWindow()` does not result in it returning `true`. Eventually it does return `true` in my code but I haven't found what causes that to happen, and it does not depend on how much time passes between the add and query.

Is this expected or should `isAttachedToWindow()` return `true` immediately?
(Android API 33, galaxy s23)

Comment: `isAttachedToWindow()` is not supposed to return true immediately. You can attach a listener to the view that will listen to any change of state of the view. This may help you: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.view.View.OnAttachStateChangeListener)